# GCloud Error pulling docker images "failed to pull and unpack image"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I am creating a fresh private node in GCloud where i have a deployment.yml with:

```
... 
containers:
  - name: print-logs
    image: busybox
    command: "sleep infinity"
```

When i review the corresponding POD, I always get this error: "failed to do request: Head https://registry-1.docker.io/... timeout"

Full logs:

```
# kubectl describe pod <my_pod>

Warning  Failed     9s                kubelet            Failed to pull image "docker.io/library/busybox:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/busybox:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/busybox:latest": failed to do request: Head https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/busybox/manifests/latest: dial tcp 3.220.36.210:443: i/o timeout
Warning  Failed     9s                kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
```

Custer settings:

```
gcloud container clusters create test-cluster \
                --preemptible \
                --enable-ip-alias \
                --enable-private-nodes \
                --machine-type n1-standard-2 \
                --zone europe-west4-a \
                --enable-cloud-logging \
                --enable-cloud-monitoring \
                --create-subnetwork name=main-subnet \
                --master-ipv4-cidr 172.16.0.32/28 \
                --no-enable-master-authorized-networks \
                --image-type COS_CONTAINERD
```

Please help me.

Comment: You have created a private cluster. You will need to configure a Cloud NAT instance to enable public Internet access: https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview

Comment: I already tried by adding Firewall rules: Allowed all (IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0) ingress and egress but it did not work. Any idea?

Comment: Why do you think the Firewall rules will help? Without Cloud NAT or a NAT instance, private instances do not have a route to the Internet. The URL `docker.io` requires Internet access.

Answer (score 2):

First connect into the cluster using[link]

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials NAME [--internal-ip] [--region=REGION     | --zone=ZONE, -z ZONE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
```

And then try to pull the docker image for docker.

For more information you can refer [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers)(which explains about Building container images).

For troubleshooting common Container Registry and Docker issues you can refer [this](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/troubleshooting) doc.